# How to get month name from an html Date input value?

Tags: javascript, html, date

This is the date input

```
<input id="customer-date" name="customer-date" type="date" required>
```

and this is the script

```
const customerDate = document.getElementById('customer-date').value;
const dateHandler = document.getElementById('date-handler');
dateHandler.innerHTML = customerDate;
```

But when I pick a date, the value I get to display in `dateHandler` is formatted like `2017-11-22` the problem is that the `format="dd/MM/yyyy"` attribute doesn't make it consistent between days and months when displaying and its obviously confusing. So I want to get the month name from the picked date to display it such `2017-November-22`. Any ideas?

Comment: did you look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp) ?

Comment: There is no [documented way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) doing this using the html5 date input. 

You will have to use your own or 3rd party javascript-implementation for doing this, or split into 3 input fields for day, month and year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the simple solution I made , I hope that helps you

```js
function showdate() {
  var customerDate = document.getElementById('customer-date').value;
  var dateHandler = document.getElementById('date-handler');
  dateHandler.innerHTML = customerDate;

  var months = new Array();
  months[0] = "January";
  months[1] = "February";
  months[2] = "March";
  months[3] = "April";
  months[4] = "May";
  months[5] = "June";
  months[6] = "July";
  months[7] = "August";
  months[8] = "September";
  months[9] = "October";
  months[10] = "November";
  months[11] = "December";

  var date = new Date(customerDate);
  var month = months[date.getMonth()];
  //converting the date into array
  var dateArr = customerDate.split("-");
  //setting up the new date form
  var forDate = dateArr[0] + "-" + month + "-" + dateArr[2];
  document.getElementById("new-date-handler").innerHTML = forDate;
}
```

```html
<input id="customer-date" name="customer-date" type="date" required>
<input type=button value=validate onclick="showdate()">
<p id="date-handler"></p>
<p id="new-date-handler"></p>
```

Comment: A date format of YYYY-MM-DD will be parsed as UTC, however you are using the local value for the month, so it will return the wrong month for a period equal to the local timezone at the start and end of the month. There is in fact no reason at all to use a Date object here. All you're doing is parsing it to a Date, then getting back the month number that was input in the first place. So just get the month number and convert it to the abbreviated name: `month = months[dateArr[1]]`.

Answer (score 2):

If you were looking to just get the month name from the month number, you could use this:

```
var str = "2017-11-22"; // this would be your date
var res = str.split("-"); // turn the date into a list format (Split by / if needed)
var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", 
"August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
console.log(months[res[1]-1]) // month name
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p8fwhydc/1/

Comment: pretty much the same as i did , just why did put an empty string at the beginning of the array ?

Comment: didn't see the answer as I posted it haha. And the empty string is because the array starts at 0. There's no '0th' month.

Comment: adding `+1` to the index is better solution i guess

Comment: Yeah you're right, you could do something like: months[res[1]-1] - edited

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Date()` javascript function like :

```
Date.prototype.getFullDate = function() {
     return this.getFullYear() + '-' + this.toLocaleString(undefined, {month:'long'}) + '-' + this.getDate();
}
const dateStr = document.getElementById('customer-date').value.split('/');
var date = new Date(dateStr[2], dateStr[1], dateStr[0]);
document.getElementById('date-handler').innerHTML = date.getFullDate();
```

Comment: `getMonth` returns a number

Answer (score 1):

When reformatting a date string, you should always consider just reformatting the string and avoiding Date objects altogether, as for Noy's answer.

However, you can also use some Date object features if you take precautions to avoid the pitfalls of parsing and formatting.

This type of question is two questions in one:

1. [How do I parse the string to a Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)
2. [How do I format the date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

In the first case, a date format of YYYY-MM-DD should be parsed as UTC (some browsers may not) so you should parse that manually.

The second part is to generate a formatted string, you can leverage the Intl object where supported to get the string in the host default language, e.g.

```js
// Parse string in YYYY-MM-DD format as local
function parseYMD(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(b[0], b[1]-1, b[2]);
}

// Format Date as D-MMMM-YYYY using host default language for month name 
function formatDMMMMY(date) {
  function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'') + n}
  return date.getFullYear() + '-' +
         date.toLocaleString(undefined, {month:'long'}) + '-' +
         z(date.getDate());
}

var s = '2017-11-22';
console.log(parseYMD(s).toString());
console.log(formatDMMMMY(parseYMD(s)));
```